# How to show a specific unit of data from a record queried in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am really stuck with dealing with querys from multiple tables in rails. If this is my controller:

```
 def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @entry = Entry.joins(:event, :user).where(users: { id: '2' })
    @event = Event.find(1)
  end
```

and this is my models

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy

class Event < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy
```

The query runs happily in rails console and returns the records but I don't know how to access specific units like `entry.course` in my embeded ruby.

**Update**

**To clarify** On a page I woulk like to output somthing for all the entries assosiated with the user logged in to the page.

eventName eventLocation eventDate course siCard

The schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171204183458) do

    # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this 
  database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

create_table "entries", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "course"
  t.string "siCard"
  t.bigint "user_id"
  t.bigint "event_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["event_id"], name: "index_entries_on_event_id"
  t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: 
  "index_entries_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_entries_on_user_id"
 end

create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "eventName"
 t.string "location"
 t.date "eventDate"
 t.text "description"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.string "eventLink"
 t.string "eventCoordinates"
 t.index ["eventName"], name: "index_events_on_eventName", unique: true
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "email"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "password_digest"
  t.string "firstName"
  t.string "remember_digest"
  t.boolean "admin"
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
end

add_foreign_key "entries", "events"
add_foreign_key "entries", "users"
end
```

Comment: What you named `@entry` is not, in fact, a single Entry object. It is a _collection_ of entries. Change your code accordingly.

Comment: People seem to speculate a lot about what you're trying to achieve. Please clarify what you intend to show in the result. One user, one event, one or more entries? Add `:course`to the models and associations. While we can guess with `@entry.course` it's probably better you would add `@course` to the controller so your code is more organized

Comment: I have tried to clarfiy what I am asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in 2 ways

1)

```
 @entries = Entry.includes(:user,:event).where(user: { id: (params[:id]) })
```

2)

```
 @entries = User.includes(entries: :event).find(params[:id]).entries
```

Than in the loop of entries you can access value course of particular entry

e.g.

```
@entries.each do |entry|
  puts "#{entry.course}"
  puts "#{entry.event&.name}"
end
```

Comment: Using `includes` associations will be loaded  in separated queries.

Comment: Yes. I know  it.

Comment: This works perfectly but is it possible to get the infomation from the event table from the foreign key in the entry

Comment: @TomSnow Yes, it is possible, i updated answer as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using such a complicated query with `joins`? If you are looking for the `Entry`s of `@user` just use `@user.entries`. ActiveRecord knows from the `has_many` how to deal with that.

If you posted a simplified example, you should try to find your Entry with something like `.where(user_id: user.id)` as long as `id` is the foreign key. With that you don't need that `join`, too.

Comment: i think he wants the entry to a specific event so

     `@entry = @user.entries.where(event_id: 1).first`

Answer (score 0):

You could confine with one query using
[`eager_load`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/eager_load)

```
def show
    @user = User.eager_load(:entries => [:event]).where(users: {id: params[:id]})
end
```

According to your models you can access entries though user.

```
@user.entries

@user.entries.map{|entry| entry.course}
```

Also you can access event (which belongs to entry) though entry.

```
@user.entries[1].event

@user.entries.map{|entry| entry.event}
```

Comment: That's alot more than 1 query. In fact only one in the Controller and many more triggered from the view which would break the MVC pattern horribly.

Comment: You right.  I spoke too soon. Answer updated. Using `eager_load` allows to make one query.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "user"` The error rails console spits out.

Comment: There should be user**s** in `where`. Answer updated.